# how do i access my array within array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

```
const arr = [ { 'days': 5,
'planDataTitle': 'Standard Plant-based meal Plan',
'breakfast': 1,
'lunch': 1,
'dinner': 1,
'entreeArry': [ [{'name':'meal plan'}], [{'quantity':1}] ] },
{ 'days': 5,
'planDataTitle': 'ION Performance Protein +',
'breakfast': 1,
'lunch': 1,
'dinner': 1,
'entreeArry': [ [{'name':'meal plan2'}], [{'quantity':2}] ] } ]


arr.forEach(function(element,index){
      meal_name = element.entreeArry[index].name
      quantity = element.entreeArry[index].quantity
      const arr = []
      newArr.push('- '+element.planDataTitle+'<br>'+ " " +mealOrder.join(',')+' for '+element.days+" days.<br>  "+meal_quantity[0].quantity+"x "+meal_name[0].name);
```

This just returns me one item, how do I get it so I can have all my items inside entreeArry I'm trying to join name and quantity for each items in my 'arr' accordingly.

Expected output could be :

```
newArr.push('- '+element.planDataTitle+'<br>'+ " " +mealOrder.join(',')+' for '+element.days+" days.<br>  "+meal_quantity[0].quantity+"x "+meal_name[0].name);
```

So I'm trying to put everything together from each array.

Comment: When you encounter an array create another `forEach` loop.

Comment: you need another loop to go through the items in entreeArry

Comment: your entreeArry is malformed. missing a } after tea it looks like. plus its all kinds of weird to be honest

Comment: `entreeArry: [ [{'name':'tea'], [{'quantity':2}] ] } ]` I'm getting confused with this over and over again. What you want to have is: `entreeArry: [ {name:'tea', quantity:2} ]`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: updated the thread

Comment: why is `entreeArry` with a nested array?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing the `index` meaning.

```js
arr.forEach(function(element,index){
  meal_name = element.entreeArry[index].name
  quantity = element.entreeArry[index].quantity
}
```

Here the value of `index` is the index of your top level array, but then you're using it for your sub-array.
In fact, you need another loop to iterate over your inner array.

```js
arr.forEach(function(plan,index){
  plan.entreeArry.forEach(function(entree){
    var meal_name = entree.name
    var quantity = entree.quantity
  }
}
```

**Note** in fact your `entryArry` is malformed. It's also an array of arrays, so in current situation you would need to get the first value, and the iterate over it.

First, you should fix your `entreeArry` into an array of objects:

```js
entreeArry: [ {name:'tea', quantity:2} ]
```

Then if you need to make a nice label to use data from both arrays based on the sample in https://pastebin.com/RJ9qFFAi

```js
arr.forEach(function(plan,index){
  var output = '- ' + plan.planDataTitle + '<br> ' +
      mealOrder.join(',') + ' for ' + plan.days + ' days.<br> ';
  plan.entreeArry.forEach(function(entree){
    var meal_name = entree.name;
    var quantity = entree.quantity;
    output += quantity + 'x ' + meal_name + '<br>';
  }
  // use your output here...
}
```

Comment: how would I go on about accessing that data outside of plan.EntreeArry?
I am trying to link that with my plan array.

Comment: you mean `plan.lunch`, `plan.days` & etc?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to join info of plan.lunc and plan.days with my entreeArry

Comment: you can use your `plan` var inside your loop.

Comment: I updated the question, I am trying to access my entree.name and quantity and concatenate it into each items in arr, accordingly @Zilvinas

Comment: @Dilli I updated the answer. First you need to fix your `entreeArry` structure, then iterate over it

Comment: but that would reiterate my meal plans multiple times... as many times as I have items inside entreeArry, the code you posted gives me output like this for instance 
https://pastebin.com/mDaXvGtm thats the output I'm getting
The expected output could be something like this:
https://pastebin.com/RJ9qFFAi

Comment: Now this sounds more like a requirement. Let me check